# Webstorm 11 'cannot resolve' warnings with folder imports

Tags: angular, webpack, webstorm

I just cloned the **[Angular 2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)**, and tried it in WebStorm 11.

It mostly works, but WebStorm complains and underlines some module import names.

For instance, in `app.component.ts`, the `{Home}` in `import {Home} from './home';` is underlined in red.

When I hover the underlined module name, it reads: `Cannot resolve symbol 'Home'`

[image: webstorm error]

If I replace `'./home'` by `'./home/index'`, though, the underlining goes away.

---

Will I have to add '/index' to all the module names, or is there a way to tell WebStorm not to worry?

Comment: sorry, just to be sure: do you mean whether I am on mac or linux? Or if you mean webpack config, it is the angular2-webpack-starter cloned from the repo

Comment: @PankajParkar I may be wrong, but I think Webpack is an alternative to system.js; there may not be any system.config, then. I found the boilerplate at this url: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter; will add it to the post...

Comment: you are correct.. webpack itself is module loader.. my bad :(

Comment: no worries. It must be some kind of WebStorm directory path config issue, it seems not to recognize node-style paths

Comment: Can you provide error message?

Comment: yes, when hovering hover module names, it reads :"Cannot resolve symbol ...(module name)"

Comment: @kemsky I have added a screenshot showing the error in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is to ... [upgrade to WebStorm 2016](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/)

---

In the meantime, here are some temporary measures you could adopt in WebStorm 11 to spare your eyes:

> **`weak warning`**

[image: weak warning]

Change the severity of the error to `Weak Warning`.

This will display the error in a less aggressive manner, while keeping the `Validate Imports` option on.

For more info about disabling Validate imports: [disable inspections in WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html)

---

> **`disable this inspection` or `suppress it for current import` (tweaks for WebStorm 11 provided by IntelliJ support team)**

One can "
either `disable this inspection` or `suppress it for current import`:

`Alt+Enter`, hit `Right`, then choose either `Disable inspection` or `Suppress for statement`
"

So you would still get the red warnings, but you can selectively act on the irrelevant ones (the ones coming from a folder import)

[image: suppress]

### ----------

### RELATED INFORMATION

**On how TypeScript resolves modules:**

"
An import statement like import { b } from "**./moduleB**" in /root/src/moduleA.ts would result in attempting the following locations for locating "./moduleB":

- /root/src/moduleB.ts
- /root/src/moduleB.ts
- /root/src/moduleB.tsx
- /root/src/moduleB.d.ts
- /root/src/moduleB/package.json (if it specifies a "typings" property)
- /root/src/**moduleB/index.ts**
- /root/src/moduleB/index.tsx
- /root/src/moduleB/index.d.ts
  "

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 2):

Resolving imports from a folder problem ([WEB-19421](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19421)) is fixed in WebStorm 2016.
Note that it only works for paths relative to current file. Webpack-specific path mappings are not supported (see [WEB-17533](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17533) and linked tickets)

Comment: good to know, will certainly consider a change/upgrade of software... But in the meantime, **with WebStorm 11**, is tweaking _'Editor > Inspections > TypeScript > Validate imports'_ the way to go?

Comment: yes, you can disable this inspection or suppress it for import using //noinspection TypeScriptCheckImport

Comment: thank you, I have included your WebStorm 11 tweak into my (rather long) answer